# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop gets stuck momentarily at times

Tags: 20.04, performance

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop alongside Windows 10.

Ubuntu gets stuck momentarily at random. Are there any solutions to this problem?

I am not able to find any similar issues with anyone else on the forum. Probably I am not stating the issue correctly, in which case I apologise.

Thanks.

I have 16 GB RAM and yes, I have a dedicated graphics card - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050.

Edit 2: (As per heynnema's comment)

Output of `free -h`

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.4Gi        12Gi        48Mi       1.3Gi        13Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Output of `sysctl vm.swappiness`

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Output of `swapon -s`

```
$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile               file        2097148 0       -2
```

Output of `top`

```
$ top

top - 09:21:12 up 14 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.43, 0.88, 0.95
Tasks: 327 total,   1 running, 326 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.6 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15889.6 total,  13029.0 free,   1483.1 used,   1377.5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2048.0 free,      0.0 used.  14071.3 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                
   1551 root      20   0   24.3g 123560  74008 S   8.3   0.8   0:30.02 Xorg                                                                                                                   
   3461 boosh   20   0  823580  52064  39256 S   6.6   0.3   0:02.73 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                        
   1750 boosh   20   0 4225016 297076 109712 S   5.0   1.8   0:47.69 gnome-shell                                                                                                            
   1134 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.7   0.0   0:05.76 irq/142-nvidia                                                                                                         
   1136 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7   0.0   0:01.14 nv_queue                                                                                                               
   1258 gdm       20   0 4114192 173864  95764 S   0.7   1.1   0:07.09 gnome-shell                                                                                                            
      1 root      20   0  167500  11592   8356 S   0.0   0.1   0:01.89 systemd                                                                                                                
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                               
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                 
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                             
      5 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0-mm_percpu_wq                                                                                               
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri                                                                                            
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                           
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_rude_                                                                                                        
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_trace                                                                                                        
     12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                            
     13 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.44 rcu_sched                                                                                                              
     14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 migration/0                                                                                                            
     15 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                          
     16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                
     17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                                                
     18 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                                                          
     19 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.16 migration/1                                                                                                            
     20 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                            
     22 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-events_highpri                                                                                            
     23 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2                                                                                                                
     24 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/2                                                                                                          
     25 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.16 migration/2                                                                                                            
     26 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                            
     28 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-events_highpri                                                                                            
     29 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3                                                                                                                
     30 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/3                                                                                                          
     31 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.16 migration/3                                                                                                            
     32 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                                            
     34 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H-events_highpri                                                                                            
     35 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/4                                                                                                                
     36 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/4                                                                                                          
     37 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.17 migration/4                                                                                                            
     38 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/4                                                                                                            
     40 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/4:0H-kblockd
```

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card? How much RAM do you have? Please edit your question. https://askubuntu.com/posts/1362066/edit

Comment: What gets stuck? The mouse? The clock? Window updates? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s` and `top`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have edited the question as per your reply. Thanks.
Everything gets stuck. I noticed it first by the stuck mouse pointer but later once when I was typing something in the terminal, characters I typed did not appear for a moment. I would like again insist that the "stuck" state is very momentary. It resumes to normalcy after just a second or two.

Comment: Thanks for the data. What version Nvidia driver do you have? It appears that you're not running Wayland. Log out. At the login screen, select your login name, then look in the lower-right corner for an icon. Click on it and select Ubuntu or Ubuntu on Wayland. Then enter your password. See if there's any improvement in the freezing.